# Don't Understand SQL parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason when I run my code, I keep getting a parameter error.

I'm running XAMP, Atom, mySql and PhpMyAdmin.
I realised maybe is was to do with the fact that I was using

```php
mysql_real_escape_string
```

which isn't supported anymore. So I changed it to mysqli, but now its showing a different error.

I'm new to the whole programming scene, so I'm quite behind with everything.

```php
    $username = "";
    $email = "";
    $errors = array();

  //connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'regist');

//if the register is clicked
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username'], $db);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email'], $db);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password_1'], $db);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password_2'], $db);
  //ensure the form fields are filled properly
  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($email)) {
    array_push($errors, "Email is required");
  }
  if (empty($password_1)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two password do not match");
  }

  //if there are no errors, save user to database
  if (count($errors)==0) {
    $password = md5($password_1); //encrypt password before storing in database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  }
}
```

I was expecting it to register the details into the database, instead i get the errors listed below.

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Resgistration\server.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Resgistration\server.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password_1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Resgistration\server.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Resgistration\server.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Resgistration\server.php on line 14

Comment: Your arguments to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` are in the wrong order. Though, just drop that function entirely  and use `$db->prepare()` with placeholders instead of `$db->query()`.

Comment: Using old methods of encrypting passwords (such as `sha1`, `md5`) are **poor methods of hashing** - you should use newer methods for hashing your passwords. PHP has a built-in [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function 
which is a lot more secure!

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` isn't enough to secure your queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, there are three things I'd like to change in your current code,

1. Your call to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has the parameters in the wrong order - it should be

   ```
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
   ```
2. You are using `md5()` for hashing your password, which is highly insecure - use `password_hash()` instead (then verify it with `password_verify()` where you log in).
3. Don't bother with 1. and instead use a prepared statement.

```
//connect to the database
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'regist');
$db->set_charset("utf8");

//if the register is clicked
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    //ensure the form fields are filled properly
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        array_push($errors, "Email is required");
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password_1'])) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }
    if ($_POST['password_1'] != $_POST['password_2']) {
        array_push($errors, "The two password do not match");
    }

    if (!count($errors)) {
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password_1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password_1']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to improve your php syntax.
First don’t MySQL ever in your code use mysqli.

Second you have given different values in the insert query than variables you defined above for your form input values.

You need to correct it.